# create an array for dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following loop that I would like to store the data (pvproduciton) in an array:

```
pvproduction is a: `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`
```

or to

```
pvproduction.sum() is a: `<class 'numpy.float64'>`
```

`pv[i]=` (how to initialize with a 10 position, the same as the loop range)

```
i=0
for i in range(0, len(pv), 1):
     pvproduction= simulating_PV(tmy_data, tilt, azimuth, modules_per_string,strings_per_inverter)
     pv[i]=pvproduction.sum()
```